# How to remove orphan commit from git history

Tags: git

I'm currently working with legacy codebase and I have an issue with git GUI tools performance.

I guess it happens because of strange commits tree in very beginning of the project.

[image: git commits history tree]

How to remove `a842c15` or `1e02e18` commits (they both dont have parents)?

I need to have just one `initial` point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple roots. This is not the same thing as an orphaned commits. Multiple roots are unfortunate, but Git is designed to work correctly with them and they should not cause performance issues. The Linux kernel itself has several.

The only way to remove the extra commits is to completely rewrite the entire history of the repository, destroying it and replacing it with a new, falsified history that does not contain the undesired history. You can do this by creating a graft and running history through `git filter-branch`.

The exact choice of graft is subtle. Looking at the graph, I don’t see an obvious choice, so I'm not sure what graft I could suggest that would get history to look the way you want it to.

If it were me, I would live with the multiple roots. I have personal repositories with far more roots—maybe 20 or 30 roots—and I experience no slowness problems with any of my tools.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply migrate to that branch by typing `git checkout a842c15` or `git checkout 1e02e18` 
after that type 
 `git reset --hard HEAD~1` this will delete commit and go 1 step ahead.
 Finally go to master branch or other by `git checkout branch_name`

Comment: This won't actually do anything. The first `git checkout` will put the repo in detached head mode, and then `git reset` won't do anything meaningful (because it's in detached head mode).